# Как использовать в openapi UploadFile в BaseModel , чтобы при этом была возможность загружать файлы FastApi

Tags: python, fastapi, openapi, pydantic

Я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы была возможность загружать файлы через openapi, но у меня не получается это сделать, если я использую модель от пайдентика.

Вот что получаеться:

```
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    photo: UploadFile
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если возможность сделать так , при этом использую модель от pydantic
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Насколько я знаю, так оно и не будет работать, как вариант можно использовать Depends(), а уже в нее передать функцию с требуемыми полями